# Ui Flows - Selenium IDE (recorder tool) - How do I store the returned value of an embedded javascript function in a webpage I am scraping?

Tags: selenium, powerapps, power-automate

Basically I want to be able to store a URL from a link I found on the webpage.  The link itself is dynamically generated by a java script function embedded within the webpage.  My question could also be satisfactorily answered by a command that grabs the current webpage URL, but I have not found any way to do that in this particular tool.

Before you ask, I cannot use a different tool, it must be this one or a Microsoft Flows / Microsoft Power Apps function/tool.  This unfortunately rules out code-based python and code-based selenium as possible solutions for me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the latest Selenium IDE. You can get the current window URL using the JS execution capabilities of the IDE.

```
"command": "executeScript",
"target": "return window.location.href"
```

Comment: if it helped you, please accept as answer to close this question.